# How can I gain an advantage in a weak no-limit Omaha Hi-Lo game?

Tags: omaha-hi-lo, home-game

I know that Omaha Hi-Lo is normally played for limit or pot-limit stakes and I think I remember there being specific reasons, but I play in a home game that occasionally plays Omaha Hi-Lo at no-limit stakes.

The people in the game are not very sophisticated Omaha players. Very rarely does anyone fold before the flop. Many people will stick around with A2 despite there being only 1 lo card on the board. Many times there are all-ins with callers and very dubious holdings. What can I do to exploit this game to the fullest?

Comment: We need more information on player tendencies to give a useful answer.

Comment: Just go all in everyhand. Man up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluff very little and play stonger starting hands than your opponents.  Don't push weak draws - you want big wraps if you are betting.  If they have poor betsizing, draw to the nuts for cheap - don't semi-bluff.  It sounds like these people will be very easy to value bet, and very difficult to bluff.  Pump up the pot when you are likely to have the best of it.

Answer (score 1):

Play a stronger range than your opponents. If they are consistently getting the money in with low equity the only really good way to profit is to have a stronger range than your opponents when the bigger pots are being played. Preflop hand selection revolves around picking hands that will flop a good high and a good low draw and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are playing against loose players, so don't bluff - you will get called anyway.

According to what you wrote, it seems that many players bet to see the flop - in this case I would have joined them (many players in the flop means bigger pot - improve your pot odds); If you miss the flop, fold to any bet. Of course, you should pay attention to the bet size - if its too expensive don't bet it.

Second point - learn the odds. One low card on the flop --> 13% to have a low. Players that stick to their cards even if they didn't hit the flop are easy prey.

I would have played a wider range of hands (not just strong hands) - many people gives too much weight to their four pocket cards "forgetting" they can use only two of them.